# jmeter and unknown host exception

Tags: jmeter

Please guide me what all are the settings needs to be done in jmeter while recording an https request through jmeter. I am getting unknown host exception while doing the same.
Thanks

Comment: what exactly are you doing?

Answer (score 3):

**Assumption 1**: you have misconfigured JMeter and/or browser. You can get JMeter configured for recording in a couple of clicks using [Templates](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature) feature.

- From JMeter's main menu select File -> Templates -> Recording -> Create
- Configure your browser to use the following proxy:

  - Proxy host: hostname or IP address where JMeter is running
  - Proxy port: **8888**
  - Use proxy for all protocols (if available) - **check**
  - Bypass proxy for local addresses (or equivalent) - **uncheck**

**Assumption 2**: you (or your company) are using corporate proxy to access Internet and/or intranet. In that case you need to pass proxy details to JMeter startup script like:

```
jmeter -H proxy_host -P proxy_port ...
```

See [Using JMeter behind a proxy](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server) guide for more information on the domain.

You can also consider an alternative solution which allows recording JMeter test right from browser without having to configure proxies, worry about SSL certificates, etc. Check out [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-load-testi/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi?hl=en)

Comment: Hi thanq so much. I launched the jmeter through command prompt and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

For unknown host exception, you should add the domain name and ip address pair in `hosts` file. For windows, this file is present at `C:\Windows\System32\driver\etc\`.

For example:
`102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com`

Answer (score -1):

For recording HTTP requests through JMeter, you have to configure some elements in your system. Steps are :

1.Add thread to test plan.

2.Add recording controller to plan

3.Add Http Proxy Server to Work Bench

4.address 127.0.0.1 port is 8888

5.Start proxy server

6.go on the recording when finished stop proxy server.

You have to configure your browser setting or install Certificates to record through JMeter. For step by step JMeter Proxy setting follow this PDF [Step by step JMeter HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)