# Getting Unknown Host Exception in JMeter while testing web application

Tags: testing, jmeter

I am getting Unknown Host Exception every time I use J meter for web testing. I can only access https sites in my company and I am not allowed to change proxy settings as its disabled in my office.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jmeter and unknown host exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36904163/jmeter-and-unknown-host-exception)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change your machine proxy settings in order to be able to use JMeter, you need to [make JMeter aware of your company proxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server)

The options are in:

1. You can pass your corporate proxy settings via [command-line options](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) **each time you run JMeter** like:

   ```
   jmeter -H your_corporate_proxy_host -P your_corporate_proxy_port
   ```
2. You can add the next lines to [JMeter *system.properties* file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   http.proxyHost=your_corporate_proxy_host
   https.proxyHost=your_corporate_proxy_host
   http.proxyPort=your_corporate_proxy_port
   https.proxyPort=your_corporate_proxy_port
   ```

Replace `your_corporate_proxy_host` and `your_corporate_proxy_port` with real values of your company proxy (if you don't know the details - contact your network administrator)